# jQuery how to make sure dialog opens before continuing script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, modal-dialog

I have the following code, which is supposed to open a modal dialog with a progress bar.  The progress bar should advance as ajax calls go one in the background.  The problem is, the dialog box is not opening until after the for loop is complete, all the ajax calls are done.  I think I am supposed to the `.promose()` function somehow, but I am not sure how to implement it in this case.  Can someone help me?

```
jQuery('#div_id')
    .button()
    .click(function(){
        var grid = jQuery('#grid_id');
        var sel_ar = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
        var last_id = 0;

        //open modal progress bar to display the progress of the emails
        jQuery('#dialog').html('<div id="progressbar"></div>');
        jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true
        });
        jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open');

        for (var i = 0;i < sel_ar.length;i++){
            var orderid = jQuery('#grid_id').jqGrid('getCell', sel_ar[i], 'order_id');

            if (last_id != orderid){
                jQuery.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: "/scripts/ajax/script.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: "orderid="+orderid,
                    success: function(data){
                        if (data != "true"){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                        jQuery('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: Math.round((i/sel_ar.length)*100) });
                    }
                });
            }
            last_id = orderid;
            pausecomp(1000);
        }
        //jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
        jQuery("#keys_list").trigger("reloadGrid");
        jQuery("#purchased_users").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
```

The `pausecomp()` is a function that just pauses for a certain number of milliseconds.  I was trying to put this in to make sure it was taking some time to complete the for loop, so I could see the progress bar ticking...  Unfortunately it just extended the time i had to wait to see the progress bar pop up after everything was all done.

I have made a fiddle that illustrates the problem.  Notice how it waits until the end of the for loop to update the progress bar. http://jsfiddle.net/YxGqG/5/

Thanks!

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. everything you want to happen after the ajax calls finish needs to be in a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the async false. it's going to lock up your browser and if the dialog hasn't been displayed, it won't display until after the ajax request.  Additionally, the async:false is going to cause the updates to the progress bar to be clunky.

Delete the line "async:false" you will then need to fix the state issue with updates to the progress bar, after you fix that issue this will work how you want it to.

Also, that lag you are seeing in the updates to the progress bar is due to using async:false.  The UI thread of the browser is in a race condition with your javascript, and when you hit the ajax call with async false, everything stops, including the "in-process" ui update to change the display of the progress bar.  That's a high level.

UPDATE
here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/xe8wF/2/ (fixed the bug that caused it to stop at 99%)

Comment: if you look at the JS fiddle I posted in the question, there is no ajax call, and it still has the same problem.  Can you make the fiddle work correctly?

Comment: Right, the problem with your js fiddle is your hogging the main thread with that pausecomp function.  If you replace it with a setTimeout, you will see that it functions as expected.

Comment: that pausecomp is only helping to prevent your desired result in your problem and should be removed. I'm guessing you added this to try and remedy the situation that was caused by using async:false.

Comment: thats because, setTimeout takes two arguments. give me a few minutes. I'll make you a new jsfiddle.

Comment: not really, I also needed to make the ajax calls have a slight pause in between them.  The ajax calls were sending SMTP emails, and the SMTP server was getting clogged and giving errors when too many emails are trying to be sent at once.  That is also why i used `async:false`.

Comment: One idea to use ajax with progress bar is to have a recursive function, that does the ajax and until the result is 100%, it updates the progress bar, then call its self again. You get the idea?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle that makes the progress bar work.  There are ways to accomplish what you want jeffrey, but async:false, and looping to create a pause are going to cause you more headaches than they will help you.

Comment: Angel's solution with setInterval is also valid, it's just blowing up on the Console object for me since work forces me to use IE.

Comment: in regards to adding a delay to prevent overload on your smtp server, don't kick off the next ajax request until the first one finishes. You should be kicking off the subsequent request from the "success" or "done" methods of the jquery ajax api. Assuming you want them sent single file. Additionally to add a delay do a setTimeout(code,Xmillseconds) inside the success or done, before you kick off the next request.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I think I will have a working script now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea you can use to make your progress bar work: (you still have to play with it to integrate it with your code, but I hope this helps you understand how you should handle ajax to update your progress bar.

```
function changeProgress(position) {
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
            value: position
    });
}

function updatePosition() {
    var position;
    $.post('ajax/get_progress', function(data) {
      // determine position from data - and store it into position
      position = ...;
      changeProgress(position);
      if(position < 100) {
          updatePosition();
      }        
    });
}
```

Hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: yes thanks, i did something similar to make the jsfiddle work: http://jsfiddle.net/YxGqG/8/